# NodeJS MongoDB: codeName: 'AtlasError' code:8000. at Connection at processMessage at TLSSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, authorization

I have this access error with mongodb and I have already tried several alternatives. I looked in the stack and saw that other users were having it too and they resolved it by creating another user and even another database. None of the alternatives worked for me. I'm using node version v14.21.3.

```
    at Connection.<anonymous> (/home/agatha.magnus/Documents/Node-JS/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:453:61)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at processMessage (/home/agatha.magnus/Documents/Node-JS/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:456:10)
    at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/home/agatha.magnus/Documents/Node-JS/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:625:15)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:400:28)
    at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:293:12)
    at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:267:9)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:206:10)
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 8000,
  codeName: 'AtlasError'
```

my connection:

```
    mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://hta:agatha@cluster0.r2eb6bu.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  )
```

Comment: can you provide the full error? Not only stack trace

Comment: the error was because of the mongoose version. I was using version 5.2.17. I updated to 7.5.3 and it worked.